# Enqueue styles in new site editor in WordPress 5.9

Tags: css, block-editor, wp-enqueue-style

In the block editor for posts and pages, I used to use the  `enqueue_block_editor_assets` hook to enqueue styles for the block.

```
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets','load_assets_in_block' );
function load_assets_in_block() {
            wp_enqueue_style(
                'block-style',
                plugins_url( 'assets/css/block-style.css', PLAYER_PLUGIN ),
                array(),
                PLAYER_PLUGIN_VERSION,
                false
            );
}
```

This still works on posts and pages block, but it isn't working on the new site editor in WordPress 5.9? What is the recommended way to enqueue styles in site editor?

Comment: I am having this same issue too. In the site editor, the styles load but all of the blocks are loaded inside an `iframe` where the styles are not loaded. So they are not applied to the blocks and they are unstyled. I have a feeling this is an issue in Wordpress more than anything.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently for the site editor, you need to add the styles a little bit differently. You need to use the `add_editor_style` function.

```php
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_add_editor_styles_to_full_site_editing');

function my_add_editor_styles_to_full_site_editing()
{
    add_theme_support('editor-styles');
    add_editor_style('site-editor.css');
}
```

**Becareful how you style your stylesheet**

This function adds your styles inline wrapped in the `.editor-styles-wrapper` class.

Comment: Just a heads-up: since 5.9, `add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );` are included by default for block themes, so it's unnecessary for this type of theme ([source](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/8db6a6e26af36004bd03ec7d9dd01e4427e6f0ad/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L4221)).